# How hide segments in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

In default, IIS hides segments `web.config`, `bin`, `App_Code` and so on.

But in sub folder of my web site have a same folder/file.

I want to hide default path and do not want not hide folder/file in sub folder.

e.g.
site url: `www.abc.com`

here after urls should deny:

```
www.abc.com/web.config
www.abc.com/bin/*
www.abc.com/App_Code/*
```

here after urls should allow

```
www.abc.com/xyz/web.config
www.abc.com/xyz/bin/*
www.abc.com/xyz/App_Code/*
```

How to configure it?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments

Comment: @Jignesh.Raj Tks, I know this topic. hidded segments will hide any access when url contain this segment. but I want hide a url only start with this segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove hidden segments for sub folders in "Request Filtering", for the `web.config` you must remove it from both `Hidden Segments` and `File Name Extensions`.

Comment: Yes, I tested this way. It can access all urls I want, but it can not protect files self in need of protection. Mean access www.abc.com/bin/xx.dll can download the assembly.

Comment: @Aimeast Sorry I cannot understand what you need

Comment: Can you understanding the example listed in question?

Comment: Yes, but there are nothing about protecting the files there.

Comment: When I clear all `Hidden Segments` and `File Name Extensions`, every objects can accessing via client browser, Including access some private objects. e.g. `www.abc.com/App_Code/*` `www.abc.com/bin/*`

Comment: Listed urls in first group should be dening and second group should be allowing.

Comment: @Aimeast I mentioned remove hidden segments of sub folder `www.abc.com/xyz/` not from the root of site

Comment: Great, I understanding your mean. But there are a new question. I have using ASP.NET MVC that all path are virtual path. Do you have a way to deny config inheriting from parents path?

Comment: @Aimeast http://runtingsproper.blogspot.fi/2010/04/solved-breaking-parent-webconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Kambiz Shahim.

My solution is:

**Set root web.config as below**

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
        <clear />
      </fileExtensions>
      <hiddenSegments>
        <clear />
      </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

**Set web.config as below of each folder which you want to hide it**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <denyUrlSequences>
          <add sequence="/" />
        </denyUrlSequences>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```